# Creating a large letter 'A' in python

Tags: python-3.x

I started printing a pyramid to start...
Here's what I made so far:`

```
num = int(input("Enter the Number: "))
for i in range(1, num+1):
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(" ", end="")

    for j in range(1, (num*2 - (2*i - 1))+1):
        if i == 1 or j == 1 or j ==(num*2 -(2*i-1)):
            print("*", end="")
    else:
        print(" ", end="")
print()
```

This is what the output should look like...

```
       *
      * *
     *   *
    *     *
   *********
  *         *
 *           *
*             *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a simple solution.

```
def large_a(height):
    rows = ["*"] + ["*" + " " * (2 * i + 1) + "*" for i in range(height - 1)]
    middle = len(rows) // 2
    rows[middle] = rows[middle].replace(" ", "*")
    return "\n".join(f"{r:^{height * 2}}" for r in rows)


print(large_a(8))

       *        
      * *       
     *   *      
    *     *     
   *********    
  *         *   
 *           *  
*             * 

print(large_a(15))

              *               
             * *              
            *   *             
           *     *            
          *       *           
         *         *          
        *           *         
       ***************        
      *               *       
     *                 *      
    *                   *     
   *                     *    
  *                       *   
 *                         *  
*                           *
```